# Dealing with rejected pull requests in azure devops

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops, pull-request

My azure devops PR was rejected, but how do I fix it?  This seems simple, but I can't find an answer online.

To resolve I have to add a few code files and remove some changes.    Do I just make the requested changes on the branch and PR again?  The PR was 99% correct so I wouldn't want to abandon it.  Do I have to abandon the original PR first?

Comment: Definitely don't create a new PR. AzDO will track updates to your branch for you and allow you to see the entire history of the PR. So either add a new commit(s) and push, or amend your existing commit(s) and force-push, and your PR will automatically get updated.

Comment: Side note, my personal preference when I want changes to be made, is to add comments regarding the desired changes, and then select "Wait for Author" instead of "Reject". IMHO "Reject" should be used to signify that I don't want this PR completed, even if fixes are made to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make additional commits on your local branch, then push those changes to the remote, it will update the existing pull request with an update.  In some cases, in-line comments about specific code will get updated (if you had a misspelling on a variable name or error message for example).

Reviewers can browse individual updates from the pull request UI.  You can see an example of how that works in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/review-pull-requests?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#review-updates).

So, fix the review items on your branch and push the changes.